# Can my separate process access to classes in my app?

Tags: java, android

I have an app that is a Firewall.  It communicates via Messenger with a VPNService running in a separate process.  I also have a `Utils` class that used both in the app and in the service.  Can the service in its separate process access this class and work fine ?

I also have other classes that are used in only one process or the other. Can the service process access these classes and work fine?

For example, in the service I perform `Utils.doSomething()` and get a `NullPointerException` and I'm uncertain whether that has to do with the two processes both using the same class.

Comment: Please paste your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no inherent reason why two processes cannot both use the same class, but it is essential to understand that in that case, each has its own copy of that class.  If you need to communicate between processes then you must make explicit provision for it.  In particular, if one process changes the values of a class's static variables, that will not ordinarily be visible to other processes.